# How do I color a SwiftUI Rectangle two different colors?

Tags: swiftui

Supposing I have a simple SwiftUI Rectangle such as:

```
Rectangle()
  .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
```

How can I color one half of it white at a 45 degree angle, and the other half black at a 45 degree angle?

My initial guess was to layer two Rectangles over each other with ZStack, but that way seems hacky to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple geometry can be achieved by transforming the shape:

```
Rectangle()
    .rotation(.degrees(45), anchor: .bottomLeading)
    .scale(sqrt(2), anchor: .bottomLeading)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .background(Color.red)
    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    .clipped()
```

Answer (score 7):

The least "hacky" way could be `Gradient`s. With a code like this:

```
Rectangle()
.fill(
    LinearGradient(
        gradient: Gradient(stops: [
            Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: 0.5),
            Gradient.Stop(color: .black, location: 0.5)
        ]),
        startPoint: .topLeading,
        endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

You get a rectangle like this:
[image: rectangle with sharp gradient stops]

What actually happens is, that SwiftUI creates two color-gradients: One from 0.0 - 0.5, from red to red and a second gradient from 0.5 to 1.0 from black to black.

Also note, that the `fill` must immediately follow the path (here `Rectangle`) as it is the `Shape` variant of `fill`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `path` for drawing this. My idea is to put `Rectangle` and `Triangle` into `ZStack`:

```swift
struct GradientRectangle: View {

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Rectangle()

            Triangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red) // here should be .white in your case
        }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

    }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))

        return path
    }
}
```

the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.red
          .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
                        
        Color.blue
          .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
      }
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      .background(
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow, Color.green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.